# Setting Apache Camel Topic Name

Tags: java, clojure, apache-camel, jms, weblogic

I'm using Apache camel to bridge a Weblogic JMS to Kafka. For the weblogic JMS I am connecting to a topic using a JDNI to get the topic name. When I inspect the object returned from my lookup on my context I see that I have the topic name

I am setting up the connection like so (this is only a proof of concept)

```
(defn topic-con-factory
  []
  (let [props (Properties.)]
    (.put props "java.naming.factory.initial" "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory")
    (.put props "java.naming.provider.url" (:host wl-ctx))
    (.put props "java.naming.security.principal" (:username wl-ctx))
    (.put props "java.naming.security.credentials" (:password wl-ctx))
    (.put props "weblogic.jndi.createIntermediateContexts" "true")
    ;;please ignore my horrible horrible abuse of let here
    (let [ctx (InitialContext. props)
          conn-factory (.lookup ctx (:factoryJNDI wl-ctx))
          wlcontext (DefaultCamelContext. ctx)
          topic (.lookup ctx (:topicJNDI wl-ctx))
          ]
      [conn-factory topic])))

(defn build-jms-component
  [factory]
  (let [jms (JmsComponent.)]
    (.setConnectionFactory jms factory)
    (.setClientId jms (:clientId wl-ctx))
    (.setDurableSubscriptionName jms (:subName wl-ctx))
    jms))

(defn camel-context []
  (let [[factory topic] (topic-con-factory)
        ctx (camel/make-context)]
    (println "topic " topic "!!!!!!!!")
    (.addComponent ctx "jms" (build-jms-component factory))
     (camel/defroute ctx
      :err-handler (camel/default-error-handler)
      (camel/from (str "jms:topic:" (.getTopicName topic)))
      (camel/to kafka-urn))
     ctx))
```

Where the wl-ctx binding is a hashmap of my various values. When I attempt to run camel-context I get the error

> Feb 01, 2017 6:11:09 PM
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer
>   handleListenerSetupFailure WARNING: Setup of JMS message listener
>   invoker failed for destination 'CENX-WL-JMS!testTopic' - trying to
>   recover. Cause: [JMSExceptions:045101]The destination name passed to
>   the createTopic or createQueue "MY-WL-SERVER!testTopic" is invalid. If
>   the destination name does not contain a "/" character, then it must be
>   the name of a distributed destination that is available in the cluster
>   to which the client is attached. If it does contain a "/" character,
>   then the string before the "/" must be the name of a JMS server or a
>   ".". The string after the "/" is the name of a the desired
>   destination. If the "./" version of the string is used then any
>   destination with the given name on the local WebLogic Server instance
>   will be returned.

From the message it looks like I need to be using "/" for the delimiter between the server name and the topic name. But if I use it instead of the bang the topic look up fails.

Is there a way to reconfigure my JmsComponent to accept ! as the delimiter instead of /?

Answer (score 0):

A mistake was made and the JMS module name was very similar to the server name. The actual topic name in this case should have been

MY_JMS_SERVER/MY_MODULE!MY_TOPIC

So doing

```
(camel/from (str "jms:topic:" (str my-server "/" (.getTopicName topic)))
```

remedied the issue.